# gallery of video clips

Tags: php, sql, gallery

on my website i have php coding and a sql database that allows users to upload images and it automatically updates the home page with new images and connects them with tags and allows u 2 pull up a page with all images connected to a tag. for the example go to fap-book.com to see the images working.

im trying to create another page that does the same thing with videos but i cant get it to play the video on the video page.

```
        <?php
        $z=1;
        $res=$ob->alltags();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $tag=$row['tags'];
                $slug=$row['slug'];
                $sno=$row['sno'];
                $img1=$ob->all($sno);

                while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($img1))
                        {
                            $img=$row1['image'];
                            $sno1=$row1['sno'];
                            $like=$row1['lik'];
                            $dislike=$row1['dislike'];

                        }


if($z==1)
{
                            echo"<div style='width:1000px;height:354px; '>
                                <div style='float:left; width:250px;'>
                                <div style='background-image:url(images/tab-top.png);width:244px;height:34px; '><div style='font-size:18px;color:#2c011f;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding-top:5px;'><a href='search.php?tag=$slug' style='font-size:18px;color:#2c011f;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding-top:5px;text-decoration:none;'>$tag</a></div></div>
                                <div style='width:240px;height:280px;background-color:#b01147; margin-left:2px;'>

<div id='gallery' style='margin-left:-40px;margin-top:-16px;'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href='images/video/$img.wmv' title=''>
                <video src='images/video/$img.wmv' style='width:240px;height:280px; ' alt='' />
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
  </div>

                                </div>
                                <div style='background-image:url(images/tab-bottom.png);width:244px;height:30px;  '>";

                echo '<div class="product_list">';



                      echo '<div class="product_like" style="float:left;margin-top:3px;margin-left:20px;"><img src="images/like.png" onclick=changeLikeDislike("lik","'.$sno1.'")> </div><div id="product_lik_'.$sno1.'" style="color:#fff;float:left;margin-top:3px;">'.$like.'</div>';
                      echo '<div class="product_dislike" style="float:left;margin-top:3px;"><img src="images/dislike.png" onclick=changeLikeDislike("dislike","'.$sno1.'")> </div><div id="product_dislike_'.$sno1.'"  style="color:#fff;float:left;margin-top:3px;">'.$dislike.'</div>';
                      echo '<div class="product_flash" id="product_flash_'.$sno1.'" style="float:left;margin-top:5px;color:#fff;font-size:12px;margin-left:5px;">&nbsp;</div>';

                      $r=mysql_query("select sno from comments where image_sno='".$sno1."'");
                      $cnt=mysql_num_rows($r);

                      echo '<div class="" id="" style="float:right;margin-top:2px;color:#fff;font-size:12px;margin-right:20px;">';

                      if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
                      {
                     echo'<a href="delete.php?sno='.$sno1.'" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/close.png" width="15" height="15"></a>';
                      }
                      echo'<a href="comments.php?id='.$sno1.'"><img src="images/comment.png" style="width:15p;height:25px;"></a></div><div style="color:#fff;float:right;margin-top:5px;">'.$cnt.'</div>';
                      echo '</div>';

                                echo"</div></div>";

}
else
{

                                echo"<div style='float:left; width:250px;'>
                                <div style='background-image:url(images/tab-top.png);width:244px;height:34px; '><div style='font-size:18px;color:#2c011f;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding-top:5px;'><a href='search.php?tag=$slug' style='font-size:18px;color:#2c011f;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding-top:5px;text-decoration:none;'>$tag</a></div></div>
                                <div style='width:240px;height:280px;background-color:#b01147; margin-left:2px;'>

<div id='gallery' style='margin-left:-40px;margin-top:-16px;'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href='images/video/$img.wmv' title=''>
                <video src='images/video/$img.wmv' style='width:240px;height:280px; ' alt='' />
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style='background-image:url(images/tab-bottom.png);width:244px;height:30px;  '>";

                                    echo '<div class="product_list">';


                      echo '<div class="product_like" style="float:left;margin-top:3px;margin-left:20px;"><img src="images/like.png" onclick=changeLikeDislike("lik","'.$sno1.'")> </div><div id="product_lik_'.$sno1.'" style="color:#fff;float:left;margin-top:3px;">'.$like.'</div>';
                      echo '<div class="product_dislike" style="float:left;margin-top:3px;"><img src="images/dislike.png" onclick=changeLikeDislike("dislike","'.$sno1.'")> </div><div id="product_dislike_'.$sno1.'"  style="color:#fff;float:left;margin-top:3px;">'.$dislike.'</div>';
                      echo '<div class="product_flash" id="product_flash_'.$sno1.'" style="float:left;margin-top:5px;color:#fff;font-size:12px;margin-left:5px;">&nbsp;</div>';

                      $r=mysql_query("select sno from comments where image_sno='".$sno1."'");
                      $cnt=mysql_num_rows($r);

                      echo '<div class="" id="" style="float:right;margin-top:2px;color:#fff;font-size:12px;margin-right:20px;">';

                       if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
                      {
                     echo'<a href="delete.php?sno='.$sno1.'" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/close.png" width="15" height="15"></a>';
                      }

                      echo'<a href="comments.php?id='.$sno1.'"><img src="images/comment.png" style="width:15p;height:25px;"></a></div><div style="color:#fff;float:right;margin-top:5px;">'.$cnt.'</div>';
                      echo '</div>';

                                echo"</div>
                                </div>";

                                if($z==4)
                                    {
                                        $z=0;
                                        echo"</div>";
                                    }

}

                                $z++;



            }

        ?>





        <div style="width:1000px;height:76px;background-image:url(images/all-top.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-left:8px; "></div>
        <div style="width:1000px;background-image:url(images/all-body.png);background-repeat:repeat-y; ">



        <table style="width:970px;margin:0 auto; " border="0">


        <?php
        $z=1;
        $res=$ob->alltags();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $tag=$row['tags'];
                $slug=$row['slug'];
                $sno=$row['sno'];
                $img=$ob->all($sno);


if($z==1)
{
                            echo"<tr><td><div style='width:238px;height:24px;background-color:#533c36;margin-right:2px; '><a href='search.php?tag=$slug' style='font-size:17px;padding-left:10px;color:#ffcc33;text-decoration:none; '>$tag</a></div><hr style='border-style:dotted;margin-top:-0px;width:238px;margin-left:-0px; '></td>";
}
else
{

                                echo"<td><div style='width:238px;height:24px;background-color:#533c36;margin-right:2px; '><a href='search.php?tag=$slug' style='font-size:17px;padding-left:10px;color:#ffcc33;text-decoration:none; '>$tag</a></div><hr style='border-style:dotted;margin-top:-0px;width:238px;margin-left:-0px; '></td>";

                                if($z==4)
                                    {
                                        $z=0;
                                        echo"</tr>";
                                    }

}

                                $z++;



            }

        ?>


        </table>
```

im not sure what i need to do to fix it or if it can be fixed

Comment: Can you narrow down the code to be just where you think the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your video is contained in a link. So it will trigger the link instead of playing the video.

```
<a href='images/video/$img.wmv' title=''>
  <video src='images/video/$img.wmv' style='width:240px;height:280px; ' alt='' />
</a>
```

Just remove the link around it, why is it even there?

Comment: copy and paste error i was doing this for 6 hours before i posted this. thanks but now it just has a black box and doesn't do anything